# Google App Scripts insert variables starting from specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script

am new to this. Am trying to insert my variables at a specific cell. With this code, the data will be written from A1:D1. Is there a way to make these variable to be written from E1:H1?. This is my source code;

```
var currentTime24 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "HH:mm");


var id  = ""+ (sheet.getLastRow() - 1); // Item1


sheet.appendRow([id, datetoday,currentTime24,comments]);

   return ContentService.createTextOutput("Attendance Recorded").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I take from your script, I add function getLastRow with filter methode, but here I assume that no blank row between your data, you can change getlastrow with get last row as usual, sheet.getLastRow(), then you check 1 by 1 up cell in column E, if you found non blank cell, it is the last row in column E, please increment 1, here you are the next row of column E...

```
var sheet = yourgooglesheet;

function getLastRow()
{
  var myRow = sheet.getRange("E:E").getValues().filter(String).length+1; 
  return myRow;
}    

function addProduct(id, datetoday, currentTime24, comments) 
{ 
  var myRow = getLastRow(); 
  var myRange = 'E' + myRow + ':H' + myRow; 
  sheet.getRange(myRange).setValues([[id, datetoday,currentTime24,comments]]);
  return;
}
```

Now you can call the function:

```
addProduct (453, new Date(), 87, "Why");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this:

```
sheet.getRange('E1:H1').setValues([[id, datetoday,currentTime24,comments]]);
```

for the flexible, set the range as follows:

```
var myRow = YourLastRowInColumn_E_After
var myRange = 'E' + myRow + ':H' + myRow; 
sheet.getRange(myRange).setValues([[id, datetoday,currentTime24,comments]]);
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain to me what is "var myRow = YourLastRowInColumn_E_After?" Is it the same as "Sheet.getLastRow()"?

Comment: getLastRow is generally get row  from our sheet, may be the last row is from any column we have, but YourLastRowInColumn_E_After, just get the last row from our column E only. May be the first, the last row in column E is not same with the last row of another column.

Comment: to take the last row of a column, you can perform: sheet.getRange("E:E").getValues().filter(String).length;

Comment: Hi, thanks for the positive feedback. I have tried the code and it doesn't work the way that i immagined it. I want to add counter. Like if there is a data from E2:H2. I want the next data to go to E3:H3. How to do that? This is my code 
`
function addProduct() {
  var id = 453;
  var datetoday = "How";
  var currentTime24 = 87;
  var comments = "Why";
  var myRow = sheet.getRange("E:E").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var myRange = 'E' + myRow + ':H' + myRow; 
  sheet.getRange(myRange).setValues([[id, datetoday,currentTime24,comments]]);}`

Comment: You must add 1, because sheet.getRange("E:E").getValues().filter(String).length is last row, so the next row you must add 1, for example: myNextRow=sheet.getRange("E:E").getValues().filter(String).length+1; and from row 1 to last row in column E must not have blank cell